# Remove all the lines that contain a specific amount of characters before delimiter

Tags: bash

## Input

## test:123456
smt:123456
test2:123456
mmm:123456
random:123456

## Expected output

## test:123456
test2:123456
random:1234567

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Soo many options:

```
$ awk -F':' 'length($1) != 3 {print}' <in.txt
test:123456
test2:123456
random:123456
$ sed  '/^...:/d' <in.txt
test:123456
test2:123456
random:123456
$ grep -v '^...:' <in.txt
test:123456
test2:123456
random:123456
$ python -c "import csv,sys; print('\n'.join([':'.join(a) for a in list(csv.reader(sys.stdin,delimiter=':')) if len(a[0]) != 3]))" <in.txt
test:123456
test2:123456
random:123456
$ perl -F: -nae 'length($F[0]) == 3 || print' <in.txt
test:123456
test2:123456
random:123456
$ ruby -F: -nae '$F[0].length == 3 || print' <in.txt
test:123456
test2:123456
random:123456
$
```